# How can I Stream bytes from a TSQL varbinary table column in .NET?

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql, t-sql, stream

In a SQL Server 2008 database, I have a table with a column of type varbinary.
Currently, I am using LINQ to SQL to access the database.
I already know that I can delay the loading of the column. However, I wish to consume less memory by not loading all of the bytes from that value.
Ideally, I would like to have a Stream to those bytes.
Is there a way I can attain this? If the answer is yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know this isn't possible using LINQ. You'll have to create your own `SqlCommand` object and call `ExecuteReader` with the `ForwardOnly` property and stream the data out manually.